# Generate random numbers in a specific range using beta distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, beta-distribution

I want to generate 1 Million and 10 Million data points in the range (0.0001,0.03) using a beta distribution with a=2.2 and b=1. Thanks in advance!

I tried this:

```
from scipy.stats import beta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
a, b = 2.2, 1
#Generated pdf of required range
x = np.linspace(0.0001, 0.03, 100)

ax.plot(x, beta.pdf(x, a, b),
       'k-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='beta pdf')

r = beta.rvs(a, b, size=1000) #Generating values
print(r)
```

The values in 'r' are not in the range (0.0001,0.03).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For for alpha and beta parameters you are using, the beta distribution is a fairly straight line from `(0, 0)` to `(1, 2.2)`.  The range you are interested in `(0.0001, 0.03)` is both a very thin slice of the 0 to 1 range, but also has a very small probability for the parameters you selected.

To actually generate 1M or 10M points, you will need to keep generating points and accumulating them to an array.

```py
from scipy.stats import beta
import numpy as np

b_dist = beta(a=2.2, b=1)
target_length = 1_000_000
points = np.array([])

while points.size < target_length:
    # generate new points
    x = b_dist.rvs(1_000_000)
    # find the indices that match criteria
    ix = x < 0.03
    ix = ix & (0.0001 < x)
    points = np.hstack([points, x[ix]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this. I tried this and successfully got data points in my required range. The only problem I faced is that the number exceeded my required number of data points, I avoided that by using another condition within the while loop. Thanks!